# Install Wildcard SSL Certificate on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, thawte

I'm not the most advanced AWS user there is, and have come across a bit of a roadblock.

I've got 2 Elastic Beanstalk Environments, each with a Load Balancer, 2 EC2 instances and they share a RDS instance. One environment is for Development and the other for Production.

I have purchased a wildcard SSL certificate from Thawte, and would like to install it on both the Development and Production environments. I've gone through other threads about adding SSL certificates in AWS, but the admin interface has changed since they were written so I've been going round in circles trying to figure it out.

Also, do I install the same SSL certificate on both Load Balancers? Or is it a case of only having one load balancer and redirecting traffic depending on the domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You will need two load balancers, one for each environment. For uploading the certificate, it sounds like you are creating your Beanstalk environment through the console. In that case, after you create the environment, go to the EC2 tab, then 'Load Balancers', then 'Listeners'. Edit that, change the protocol to https. You'll see there is a place to change the certificate:

[image: change ssl cert]

That will give you a place to upload the certificate:

[image: upload cert]

Now that the cert is there, you can use the Elastic Beanstalk configuration to change future environments to use that cert:

[image: network tier config]

Comment: Thanks, you're response led me to an answer, the cert chain was slipping me up